# My Android is not dead even if i kill it from 'recent' on android device

Tags: android, android-studio

After I kill my app from 'recent' from android app, it show my app 'dead' in Logcat for just a sec then following is written in logcat:

```
03-07 20:40:18.779 27282-27282/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-07 20:40:18.779 27282-27282/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:27282
03-07 20:40:19.019 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:19.299 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:19.739 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:19.859 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:19.879 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:19.949 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:19.949 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:20.049 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:20.059 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:20.159 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:20.169 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:20.239 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:20.239 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:20.309 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:20.309 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:20.379 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:20.379 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:20.439 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:20.439 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:20.529 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:20.539 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/art: override thread count:-j4
03-07 20:40:20.599 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@lcukerd.com.stufflist-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
03-07 20:40:20.619 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/lcukerd.com.stufflist-1/lib/arm64
03-07 20:40:20.659 27282-27282/lcukerd.com.stufflist I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for lcukerd.com.stufflist
```

My AndroidStudio version : 2.3

Any idea why this is happening? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you start background threads before stopping the main UI thread? so them keep going

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I haven't added any background thread.